# arrayWithContentsOfFile can't read plist file

Tags: iphone, nsarray, plist, nsbundle

i have a plist with an array that contain 2 strings see image :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/263/myplist.png/

and in my `viewDidLoad` i add this :

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle  mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data"    ofType:@"plist"];

NSArray *array = [NSArray    arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];

NSLog(@"array = %@", array);
```

But i got always `null` why? Thanks for help.

UPDATE : the solution is that you need to manually edit the plist file (Xcode4 use Dictionnary by default)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <array>
        <string>HO</string>
        <string>HI</string>
    </array>
</array>
</plist>
```

Comment: @funnyCoder Did you check that the path exists? Maybe stick a `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file]` in there?

Comment: @Aravindhanarvi This is my full code :).

Comment: @Jacob : i checked and the path exists.

Comment: @funnyCoder:change the name of the root Key From Array TO Root It is Working fine

Comment: @nikhil : I changed it to root but doesn't work!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely, your plist is a dictionary that contains an array (Xcode 4 doesn't allow to create plists with an array as the root object). Try something like this:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file];
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"Array"];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Comment: @omz dude it allow to create actually  allow to create array as a root

Comment: I will give you a good answer :), because it's ok, but the correct answer is that you need to edit by hand te plist file.

Comment: @nikhil You can do it in Xcode 3 (as the screenshot in your answer shows), but not in Xcode 4, which is shown in funnyCoder's screenshot. I found it hard to believe myself.

Comment: You can edit the Dictionary plist in TextEdit (or elsewhere), remove the <dict>, </dict> and key, then reopen the file in Xcode and edit it like normal.  Then when you load it, it will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: plist should start with Root Key]

in you application you need to change the root  key name as  it can not be datatype

Comment: I changed it but no success, it seems that Xcode 4 doesn't allow array plist?!

Comment: So hiw to deal with that? you can give me an URL about Xcode4 Array plist support? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been studied this topic and discover some differences in plist file.

For example ,  I have the original plist file in sample code that is read with 
the method
`NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];`

the xml original file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">

<array>
<dict>
    <key>nameKey</key>
    <string>Number One</string>
    <key>imageKey</key>
    <string>small_one.png</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>nameKey</key>
    <string>Number Two</string>
    <key>imageKey</key>
    <string>small_two.png</string>
</dict>

</array>        
</plist>
```

When I tried to create this same file above in Xcode Interface, using Add new File Property List, and after editing puting the item the same way is show in interface for the file above, the method `[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];` fail, and I found the issue at structure of xml plist file. 
The file created using XCode Interface, result in xml plist file  :

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>item 0</key>
<dict>
    <key>imageKey</key>
    <string>image1.jpg</string>
</dict>
<key>item 1</key>
<dict>
    <key>imageKey</key>
    <string>image2.jpg</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I fixed change direct in xml file as same the first example, and the method works fine.

The point is in XCode interface for plist file, you cant see these differences. The both look the same. Maybe is my Xcode 4.1

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is, the root item IS already an array (in XCode4.. not sure about the others). So if you put another array as *neil d* showed in his screen shot, you will end up with an array that contains an array with the two string values.

Answer (score 0):

`plist` of this type:

[image]

OR (basically both are same)

[image]

Can be read like this:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"appFeatures" ofType:@"plist"];
_arrFeats = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];
NSLog(@"%i", _arrFeats.count);
```

Where `appFeatures` is name of the `plist`.
(iOS 6.1)