# Selecting random word from plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [displaying a random word from a plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405047/displaying-a-random-word-from-a-plist)

I have a plist with some words in it now I try to display a random word of that plist but my app crashes and I don't know how to solve the problem.

**this is my code:**

```
NSArray *randomAddons = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wordsENG" ofType:@"plist"]];

NSLog(@"Array: %@", randomAddons);

int randomIndex = arc4random() % [randomAddons count];

mainTextController.text = [username2 stringByAppendingString:[randomAddons objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
```

**this is the crash:**

```
Array: (
    (
    DANDAN,
    DONDON,
    SAMSAM,
    SANSAN
)
)
2012-07-10 11:23:28.047 spinningyarn[336:1bb03] -[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0xa26cad0
2012-07-10 11:23:28.047 spinningyarn[336:1bb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa26cad0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b04022 0x1ee0cd6 0x1b05cbd 0x1a6aed0 0x1a6acb2 0x1468bd9 0x115dc3 0x3de995 0x979ed9 0x981725 0x8ea4ab 0x9837c6 0x8c9885 0x2166330 0x2168509 0x1a3b803 0x1a3ad84 0x1a3ac9b 0x26287d8 0x262888a 0xb3d626 0x29e2 0x2955 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

I hope someone can help me out

Comment: Repost of [displaying a random word from a plist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405047/displaying-a-random-word-from-a-plist). Please don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

randomAddons is an Array containing one Array...

try this:

```
NSArray *randomAddons = [(NSArray*)[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wordsENG" ofType:@"plist"]] objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"Array: %@", randomAddons);

int randomIndex = arc4random() % [randomAddons count];

mainTextController.text = [username2 stringByAppendingString:[randomAddons objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
```

Comment: That works! thanks a lot! Can get on with my project now!:D

Comment: then, it would be nice if the answer gets accepted. Thanks